# passing std::string to native thread

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I need to pass binary data to a native thread.
I am using std::string to keep the binary data, I came up with an idea how to pass std::string to a native string, and want to know if it is safe.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    string binaryDataInThread = string(*(string*)lpParam); // copy data to current thread
    while (true)
    {// do some stuff with binaryDataInThread
        cout << "thread binaryData size: " << binaryDataInThread.size() << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
        string binaryDataInMain;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            binaryDataInMain += (char)i;
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MyThreadFunction, &binaryDataInMain, NULL, NULL));
        Sleep(1000); // wait for thread to copy data
    } // destroy binaryDataInMain
    system("pause");
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

the size of binaryDataInThread is 500, so all binary data has passed successfully. but is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

No your method is not save, although it is unlikely to fail. Under odd circumstances, even the second you wait for the thread to copy the data is not enough.

Suggestions:

- Use C++ threads.
- If for some odd reason you can't use C++ threads, fix those reasons!
- If you pass data to a thread that you want to avoid sharing, allocate the data dynamically using `new`. Of course, the thread will then be responsible for releasing the data using `delete`!
- If you want to share data with a thread, synchronize access to it using the various sychronization primitives available (mutex, events etc).
- As alternative, use atomic operations on primitive types. However, lock-free programming is hard and correct lock-free programming is even harder. This is *not* for beginners!